# JQuery parent() hide() within ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to be able to delete a user from a table then hide the div which shows them.

A user clicks on a button with class `.buddy_delete` which contains the info to pass to the php file which deletes them.

I have the following which works ok, but I need the `$(this).parent().hide();` in the AJAX response instead of before the AJAX in case of any error, is this possible?

```
$('.buddy_delete').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var sei = $(this).attr('sei');
        var sui = $(this).attr('sui');
        $(this).parent().hide(); // ok here
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/ajax/actions/remove_user_from_list.php?sei=' + sei + '&sui=' + sui,
            success: function (data) {
                if(data==='ok'){
                    // $(this).parent().hide(); // doesn't work here, nothing happens
                } else {
                    $('#errorBoxEvent').html('Houston, we have a problem!');
                }
            }
        }); // End .ajax function
    });
```

Comment: have you tried `console.log(data)` to see what you get back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set option context of ajax method:

```
$.ajax({
   context: this,
   //...
});
```

Comment: Hmmm, never came across that before, am reading up on it - thanks for the answer, it's appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use closure to capture $(this):

```
$('.buddy_delete').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var sei = $(this).attr('sei');
    var sui = $(this).attr('sui');
    var $that = $(this);  //capture this
    $(this).parent().hide(); // ok here
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/ajax/actions/remove_user_from_list.php?sei=' + sei + '&sui=' + sui,
        success: function (data) {
            if(data==='ok'){
                $that.parent().hide(); //use here 
            } else {
                $('#errorBoxEvent').html('Houston, we have a problem!');
            }
        }
    }); // End .ajax function
});
```